# A jQuery line of code makes my cursor turn to 'text cursor'?

Tags: jquery

In Firefox my cursor turns into the one you see when you select a text field (I'm using Ubuntu 11.04).

The problem seem to be the commented line below (because the cursors returns to default or pointer if I comment it):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function(){
        var btnUpload=$('#upload');
        var status=$('#logo-upload-status');
        new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/upload-file.php',
            name: 'uploadfile',
            /* this is the problem -> onSubmit: function(file, ext){  */
                 if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){
                    status.text('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');
                    return false;
                }
                status.text('Uploading...');
            }
            onComplete: function(file, response){
                //On completion clear the status
                status.text('');
                //Add uploaded file to list
                if(response==="success"){
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file).addClass('success');
                    $('#<?php echo $logo_image; ?>').val(file);
                } else{
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

The button:

```
   <input type="button" class="background_pattern_button" id="upload" value="Choose Logo" />
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Firebug Inspector (For some reason the cursor looks normal in the screenshot):

[image]

Comment: All your JS would break if you commented just that 1 line. Do you mean you commented out the whole method?

Comment: You're also missing a `,` before the `onComplete`, but you're code will be broken either way if you comment that one line out.

Comment: @JohnP Yes, I think the problem is the whole `onSubmit` function.

Comment: @alexchenco I don't think the issue is there. The problem probably goes away because the JS has stopped at that point. Do you have a sample page we can look at?

Comment: @JohnP is the backend of my Wordpress admin.

Comment: inspect the element with firebug and see where the cursor property is being added.

Comment: @JohnP OK I posted the result of the firebug inspector.

Comment: @alexchenco can't really help with the screenshot. When you look at it, doesn't a cursor property show up anywhere in firebug?

Comment: @JohnP No there is nothing in the CSS. But there is a javascript: `<input type="file" name="uploadfile" style="position: absolute; margin: -5px 0pt 0pt -175px; padding: 0pt; width: 220px; height: 30px; font-size: 14px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer; display: none; z-index: 2147483583; top: 262px; left: 516px;">` (Not sure where it comes from).

Comment: @alexchenco Does it appear as soon as the page loads? In any case, you should use Firebugs debugger to step through your code. That might be your best bet

Comment: @JohnP I think that input is resting above the button (which may be the cause of the problem). But if I take it out, I can't upload any file. And yes, I appears as soon the page loads.

Comment: @alexchenco so does it go away when you move the input to another row?

Comment: @JohnP Yes it goes away but the upload no longer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax Upload uses a method of a hidden `<input type="file" />` which in turn allows you to have a personalised "browse computer" button which will open a file etc etc etc. The problem you are facing is that you cannot change the cursor of the `<input type="file" />`

You just have to put up with it, or push the input to the left a little with css so the button area gives the default cursor instead of text.

Also your input should have a opacity which makes it invisible to naked eye but it is there none the less [on css]

Comment: in my opinion yes, as browsers have treated this as security risk,treated as many people will misguide (non-computer-literals), which I think it's silly, if they don't know that selecting file window, allows u to upload something, they wudn't know about mouse cursor difference lol :)